# Get the average value from a vector of Integers

Tags: c++, vector

I have been unable to find a way of getting the average value from a vector of integers in C++.

I can't possibly start adding all of the values because I could exceed the maximum integer accepted value.

How can I calculate this efficiently and quickly ? Are there any standard libraries in the C++ language to do that ?

Comment: You could do the accumulation in a `double`.  Since the average of integers need not be an integer, it seems you're going to need floating-point anyway.

Comment: Then don't accumulate into an `int` (use a `uint64_t` instead, for example).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I have a really big vector of 23 million integers, I don't think this way would work. Isn't there a way to do this other than manually ?

Comment: @5gon12eder - Depends on how many there are - if the sum goes above 2^53, then `double` will lead to imprecise results.  (Limit for `uint64_t` is 2^64.)

Comment: @Shiro: 23 million is substantially less than 2^64 / 2^32.

Comment: What is wrong with `std::accumulate( vector.begin(), vector.end(), 0.0) / vector.size();`

Comment: You could use `int64_t` if your vector has 32-bit integers. If you have 64-bit integers, you could use `__int128_t` or equivalent (assuming your compiler provides it).

Comment: Common guys, if you have to do an average of 1Mio integers, event with long  (or rather said long long) he'll overflow. And with doubles, he'd have a terrible loss of precision in the average.  He really needs something more...

Comment: @Christophe - 1 million will *not* overflow (assuming we mean `int` by "integer").

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth if he'd adds 1 million of integers, each being around MAX_INT/2 he will certainly overflow...

Comment: @Christophe - Not if accumulating into a 64-bit type (assuming the original vector contains 32-bit values).

Comment: 23 million * int32_max easily fits into a 64 bit integer. As long as you don't have more than 4 billion ints (2^32 to be precise) in the vector, accumulating into an `int64_t` will do nicely.

Comment: You can definitely do that with a simple formula as long as you know count of elements. Let's assume vector is a. So formula will be. S+= a[i]/n

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The go-to approach is just summing with a sufficiently wide integer type with [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
double avg1(std::vector<int> const& v) {
    return 1.0 * std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0LL) / v.size();
}
```

**If** this sum overflows (with 23 million ints, the average would have to be at least 4.01x10<sup>11</sup> - which is to say, it won't overflow since that won't even fit in an `int32_t`... so you're way good, but on the off chance you get several orders of magnitude more numbers, or have wider a `int` type), then you can instead use the common "online" algorithm for calculating the mean:

```
double avg2(std::vector<int> const& v) {
    int n = 0;
    double mean = 0.0;
    for (auto x : v) {
        double delta = x - mean;
        mean += delta/++n;
    }
    return mean;
}
```

This won't overflow, isn't very prone to loss of precision, but may be more expensive due to repeated extra divisions.

Comment: Is there a resource where an analysis of the error propagation of avg2 is given?  I find it hard to understand where this would make a difference to the *naive* std::accumulate with a double `T init`.  With double 16-17 digits; and 32-bit int 10 digits. 64-bit int about 20 digits.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2683386?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) or [tandf](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1974.10480219)

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe - Imagine a vector with 2^53 entries, each of value `1` (could also come up with examples that require way fewer entries...)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That vector would be computationally prohibitive. =)

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe - Indeed!  But illustrates the issue - once input values fall below the ULP of the accumulator, they don't contribute.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been unable to find a way of getting the average value from a
>   vector of integers in C++.  I can't possibly start adding all of the
>   values because I could exceed the maximum integer accepted value.  How
>   can I calculate this efficiently and quickly ? Are there any standard
>   libraries in the C++.

A lot of discussion of finding a sum that might be too big for even a uint64_t.

So follow this suggestion and stop worrying ...

I have used, can recommend, and am very impressed with the multi-precision C++ library called "gmpxx.h".

I have used it for several interesting efforts, including code to generate a big fibonacci with no apparent effort.  It is easy to use, and surprisingly quick, and I have found on the web examples of how to use.

Code snippet:

```
mpz_class  n;   // a multi-precision integer, 
n = 1;          // easy initialize
size_t F = 1000; 
for (size_t i=1; i<=F; ++i)
   n = n * i;
// show
std::string Fstr = digiComma(n);  // inserts comma's
std::cout << "\n" << F << "! = " << Fstr
          << "\n" << digitCnt(Fstr) << " bytes " <<  std::endl;
```

My output is a 2568 character (>1900 digits), comma delimited, big int value in < 20 ms.

> 1000! = 
>   402,387,260,077,093,773,543,702,433,923,003,985,719,374,864,210,714,632,543,799,
>           910,429,938,512,398,629,020,592,044,208,486,969,404,800,479,988,610,197,196,058,
>           631,666,872,994,808,558,901,323,829,669,944,590,997,424,504,087,073,759,918,823,
>           627,727,188,732,519,779,505,950,995,276,120,874,975,462,497,043,601,418,278,094,
>           646,496,291,056,393,887,437,886,487,337,119,181,045,825,783,647,849,977,012,476,
>           632,889,835,955,735,432,513,185,323,958,463,075,557,409,114,262,417,474,349,347,
>           553,428,646,576,611,667,797,396,668,820,291,207,379,143,853,719,588,249,808,126,
>           867,838,374,559,731,746,136,085,379,534,524,221,586,593,201,928,090,878,297,308,
>           431,392,844,403,281,231,558,611,036,976,801,357,304,216,168,747,609,675,871,348,
>           312,025,478,589,320,767,169,132,448,426,236,131,412,508,780,208,000,261,683,151,
>           027,341,827,977,704,784,635,868,170,164,365,024,153,691,398,281,264,810,213,092,
>           761,244,896,359,928,705,114,964,975,419,909,342,221,566,832,572,080,821,333,186,
>           116,811,553,615,836,546,984,046,708,975,602,900,950,537,616,475,847,728,421,889,
>           679,646,244,945,160,765,353,408,198,901,385,442,487,984,959,953,319,101,723,355,
>           556,602,139,450,399,736,280,750,137,837,615,307,127,761,926,849,034,352,625,200,
>           015,888,535,147,331,611,702,103,968,175,921,510,907,788,019,393,178,114,194,545,
>           257,223,865,541,461,062,892,187,960,223,838,971,476,088,506,276,862,967,146,674,
>           697,562,911,234,082,439,208,160,153,780,889,893,964,518,263,243,671,616,762,179,
>           168,909,779,911,903,754,031,274,622,289,988,005,195,444,414,282,012,187,361,745,
>           992,642,956,581,746,628,302,955,570,299,024,324,153,181,617,210,465,832,036,786,
>           906,117,260,158,783,520,751,516,284,225,540,265,170,483,304,226,143,974,286,933,
>           061,690,897,968,482,590,125,458,327,168,226,458,066,526,769,958,652,682,272,807,
>           075,781,391,858,178,889,652,208,164,348,344,825,993,266,043,367,660,176,999,612,
>           831,860,788,386,150,279,465,955,131,156,552,036,093,988,180,612,138,558,600,301,
>           435,694,527,224,206,344,631,797,460,594,682,573,103,790,084,024,432,438,465,657,
>           245,014,402,821,885,252,470,935,190,620,929,023,136,493,273,497,565,513,958,720,
>           559,654,228,749,774,011,413,346,962,715,422,845,862,377,387,538,230,483,865,688,
>           976,461,927,383,814,900,140,767,310,446,640,259,899,490,222,221,765,904,339,901,
>           886,018,566,526,485,061,799,702,356,193,897,017,860,040,811,889,729,918,311,021,
>           171,229,845,901,641,921,068,884,387,121,855,646,124,960,798,722,908,519,296,819,
>           372,388,642,614,839,657,382,291,123,125,024,186,649,353,143,970,137,428,531,926,
>           649,875,337,218,940,694,281,434,118,520,158,014,123,344,828,015,051,399,694,290,
>           153,483,077,644,569,099,073,152,433,278,288,269,864,602,789,864,321,139,083,506,
>           217,095,002,597,389,863,554,277,196,742,822,248,757,586,765,752,344,220,207,573,
>           630,569,498,825,087,968,928,162,753,848,863,396,909,959,826,280,956,121,450,994,
>           871,701,244,516,461,260,379,029,309,120,889,086,942,028,510,640,182,154,399,457,
>           156,805,941,872,748,998,094,254,742,173,582,401,063,677,404,595,741,785,160,829,
>           230,135,358,081,840,096,996,372,524,230,560,855,903,700,624,271,243,416,909,004,
>           153,690,105,933,983,835,777,939,410,970,027,753,472,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,
>           000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,
>           000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,
>           000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,
>           000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

2568 bytes

real    0m0.013s

user    0m0.004s

sys     0m0.000s

So how big is a uint64_t?  I think the biggest Fib that fits in uint64_t is Fib(93).

Comment: This tool is integer precise, no float/double approximations, and I doubt this has any limit but your ram.

Comment: It is C++, but with a few implications from it's C underpinnings.  Is it a "standard libary"?  I think so, but you are asking the question.

Comment: GMP lib  "GNU Multiprecision Library" -- initial release 1991, 25 yrs ago. Latest stable release 6.1.0 (1 November 2015; 4 months ago).

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that you don't have to store the entire sum of the vector. You can divide integers during iteration and store the remainder to add it to the next value.

This allows to create algorithm that is very memory efficient. I didn't make a benchmark but it should be OK for processors that have hardware division module.

Here a solution that shouldn't overflow as long as `el + vector.size()` fits into `ACCU_T` for each element of the vector. It should be possible to remove this limitation if we use processor overflow flag.

```
template<typename T, typename ACCU_T = uintmax_t>
T vec_average(const std::vector<T> &vec)
{
    const ACCU_T size = (ACCU_T)vec.size();
    T avg = 0;
    ACCU_T accu = 0;
    for (const T &el : vec)
    {
        accu += (ACCU_T)el;
        avg += (T)(accu / size);
        accu %= size;
    }
    return avg;
}
```

It doesn't use any floating point or big numbers.
The variable of `accu` has a value of `sum(vec) % vec.size()` at the end of function.

---

Yep, here's a version for GCC and Clang that shouldn't overflow for any unsigned integer.

(The exact constraint here is that `el + vector.size()` cannot be bigger that 2 times as much as ACCU_T can fit.)

```
template<typename T, typename ACCU_T = uintmax_t>
T vec_average(const std::vector<T> &vec)
{
    const ACCU_T size = (ACCU_T)vec.size();
    const T overflowAvg = (T)((ACCU_T(-1)) / size);
    const ACCU_T overflowAccu = overflowAvg * size;
    T avg = 0;
    ACCU_T accu = 0;
    for (const T &el : vec)
    {
        if (__builtin_add_overflow(accu, (ACCU_T)el, &accu))
        {
            avg += overflowAvg;
            accu -= overflowAccu;
        }
        avg += (T)(accu / size);
        accu %= size;
    }
    return avg;
}
```